# Как в java открыт файл и записать эти данные в другой файл?

Tags: java

Как в java открыт файл и записать эти данные в другой файл?

Answer (score 7):

Если использовать только стандартные средства, то в упрощённом виде так:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/file"));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStram(new File("/path/to/destination/file"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
int rc;

while((rc = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, rc);
}

fos.close();
fis.close();
```